# tar files after reducing list via find and grep?

Tags: grep, find, tar

I have worked out this command to give me the list of files I want to send to tar, how do I send this list to tar?

```
find . -not -type l | grep -E "(^\.\/bin\/custom|^\.\/config\/local)" | grep -v -E "(.settings|.classpath|.external)"
```

1. I want to preserver the hierarchy of bin/custom and config/local*
2. I don't want any other files (which there are a LOT of), the bin/custom is a directory and config/local* are files in config
3. I don't want any symbolic links
4. I want to exclude some of the hidden files (.settings|.classpath|.external)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use construction like this:

```
tar cvf tarfile.tar $(find . -type f | grep -E "(^\.\/bin\/custom|^\.\/config\/local)" | grep -v -E "(.settings|.classpath|.external)")
```

You just provide the list of files to be added in to the tar archive.

And its not need to use `-not -type l`, `-type f` will provide only files (and not links)
In case of many file something like can resolve the issue:

```
find . -type f | grep -E "(^\.\/bin\/custom|^\.\/config\/local)" | grep -v -E "(.settings|.classpath|.external)"|xargs tar cvf tarfile.tar
```

Comment: So this worked initially but I tried to use it again and I am getting the error: **zsh: argument list too long: tar** I am assuming this means there are too many files, any suggestions for fixing this issue?

Comment: Thank you for a perfect answer and more importantly, a superfast reply.  I really appreciate it!